# Split alphanumeric strings by space and keep separator for just first occurence

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to split and then join the first alphanumeric occurrence by space and keep other occurrences as it is, but not getting the pattern to do that.
For ex:
string: Johnson12 is at club39
converted_string: Jhonson 12 is at club39

**Desired Output:**

```
input = "Brijesh Tiwari810663 A14082014RGUBWA"

output = Brijesh Tiwari 810663 A14082014RGUBWA
```

Code:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("[0-9]{1,}")
testString = "Brijesh Tiwari810663 A14082014RGUBWA" # fill this in
a = re.split('([^a-zA-Z0-9])', testString)
print(a)
>> ['Brijesh', ' ', 'Tiwari810663', ' ', 'A14082014RGUBWA']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.  We can use `re.findall` on the pattern `[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+`, which will alternatively find all letter or all number words.  Then, join that resulting list by space to get your output

```py
inp = "Brijesh Tiwari810663 A14082014RGUBWA"
output = ' '.join(re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+', inp))
print(output)  # Brijesh Tiwari 810663 A 14082014 RGUBWA
```

**Edit:** For your updated requirement, use `re.sub` with just one replacement:

```py
inp = "Johnson12 is at club39"
output = re.sub(r'\b([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)\b', r'\1 \2', inp, 1)
print(output)  # Johnson 12 is at club39
```

Comment: Hey can you help me on this again?

Comment: I am trying to split and then join the first alphanumeric occurrence by space and keep other occurrences as it is, but not getting the pattern to do that. For ex: string: Johnson12 is at club39 converted_string: Jhonson 12 is at club39

Comment: @GauravBatheja My answer is already working for your alternative input, [see the demo here](https://rextester.com/AZAFC99234).  You should accept my answer in this case.

Comment: I accept that it is working but I just want separate by first occurrence, but your code is separating club39 to club 39

Comment: will  setting count = 1 work?

Comment: Check my updated answer again.

Comment: This is working for me                                                                                            
`pattern = r'[0-9]+'
output = re.sub(pattern,'', inp, count=1)`